# What is the major difference between SimpMessageHeaderAccessor vs StompHeaderAccessor Spring + java

Tags: java, spring, stomp

What is the major difference between SimpMessageHeaderAccessor vs StompHeaderAccessor Web Socket Spring?

Please explain elaborately if you know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a simple answer: [SimpMessageHeaderAccessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.html) is the parent of [StompHeaderAccessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/stomp/StompHeaderAccessor.html).

That is, StompHeaderAccessor is used exclusively for STOMP headers while SimpMessageHeaderAccessor is used for all messaging protocol headers, including STOMP.

---

STOMP is one of the simpler types of messaging protocol - it's text based, making it a little similar to how HTTP works and allows for communication using multiple languages and platforms. But it cannot be used for queuing and topics.

Further reading:

1. http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/
2. https://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html

Answer (score 2):

Its important to understand the [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/) protocol, its design and format to better understand the API and the [classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/stomp/StompHeaderAccessor.html) related.

STOMP´s interoperable wire format allows clients to communicate with number of message brokers. Since its language agnostic, clients and brokers developed in different languages can send and receive messages to each other.

STOMP complient message brokers are [here](https://stomp.github.io/implementations.html).

STOMP is text-based and does not use binary protocols. It supports a range of core enterprise messaging features, such as authentication, messaging models like P2P & publish and subscribe, message acknowledgement, transactions, message headers & properties, etc.,

So while you use Spring Messaging framework to build client and server side Messaging platforms and applications, the package `org.springframework.messaging.simp` has generic support for Simple message protocols, STOMP is ONE of them.

As a base class of `StompHeaderAccessor`, can use `SimpMessageHeaderAccessor` for generic message header properties and use `StompHeaderAccessor` for STOMP specific properties like `ContentLength`, `createForHeartbeat()`, `isHeartbeat()` etc., and STOMP messaging API specific methods like `updateStompCommandAsClientMessage()`, `updateStompCommandAsServerMessage()`, `wrap(Message<?> message)`.

Good examples on using StompHeaderAccessor can be found [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor). 
A good working example of using both SimpMessageHeaderAccessor and StompHeaderAccessor is available in this [blog](http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-session-stomp-websocket).